# How to assure mypy that user input is in a set of literals

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

My code is basically the following:

```py
def foo(param: Literal["a", "b"]) -> None:
    ...

i = input("A or B?").lower()
assert i in ["a","b"]
foo(i)
```

However mypy complains that it can't know that

```
Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Union[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]"
```

and I can't find documentation on how to convert this to a literal expression.

Comment: you can use `typing.cast`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you want to write this up as an answer or should I write it up and self answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned in a comment, you can use `typing.cast` to cast the value as an element. Unfortunately mypy doesn't appear to do any checking on `type.cast` that the value actually fits the literal it is being cast to, but you can do that check for that yourself against `typing.get_args`.

```
a_or_b=Literal["a", "b"]
def foo(param: a_or_b) -> None:
    ...


i = input("A or B?").lower()
if not i in typing.get_args(a_or_b):
    raise ValueError()
else:
    i = typing.cast(i,a_or_b)
foo(i)
```